# how to install different ionic version in different node using nvm

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, nvm

I am using multiple versions of node using nvm to develop my ionic projects. I started with ionic 3 so by default my system installs ionic 3 in every version.Now I want to install the latest ionic cli but cannot do it. I tried the uninstall command to remove ionic 3 but no matter what I try I am not able to remove the ionic 3 from one of my nvm. Please help me to remove it without affecting the other version.